# How do I edit text in Visio files (vsdx) using python?

Tags: python, visio, open-packaging-convention

I am trying to automate some translation work where I just need edit all the texts in Visio (**`vsdx`**) files, the diagram does not need to be changed.

I have been searching for ways to perform such action but I can't find anything useful.

How do I import `vsdx` to python, edit texts globally then export a `vsdx`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should read more about **VSDX Drawing File Format**. Here are several references:

1. [Visio VSDX Drawing File Format](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000021.shtml)
2. [Introduction to the Visio file format (.vsdx)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/introduction-to-the-visio-file-formatvsdx)
3. [Manipulate the Visio file format programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/how-to-manipulate-the-visio-file-format-programmatically)

Also, get familiar with [**Open Packaging Conventions and XML**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Packaging_Conventions) or [**ECMA 376**](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) - this standard the new `vsdx` is based on (tiny hint: `vsdx` is a usual archive).

After that you will figure out that basically there are a lot of libraries written even in python that works in some way with `vsdx`.

Update: as **Nikolay** politely noted, actually there are no so many libraries to work with this kind of files. So, my wording here (a lot of) is simply incorrect.
On the contrary, there are few articles explaining how to deal with the `vsdx` format.

Comment: Could you name at least one python library that can at least read and write vsdx files (you said that there are "a lot" of them)..?

Comment: Will the first one from the Google work for you? https://github.com/thiezn/visiopy
Anyway, the spec is open, why not untar the file and find the XML that describe the text and work with it as you wish?

Comment: I did a more detailed search, and you're right. My wording ("a lot") is simply incorrect - I will update my answer. Thx.

Comment: I have figured it out and yes gahcep is right, the logic is to rename, unzip, operate on the XMLs. With the help of beautifulsoup I manage to edit all the texts easily.

Comment: can you please provide us a code sample for working on the underlying XML of the visio files?

Comment: I used beautifulsoup to parse the XML within the vsdx, you can edit text by re-assigning items inside bs4.element.ResultSet to your desired text, then write the edited soup object to a new XML (or replace your old one)